# Why does the code stop executing after the scanf?

Tags: c

```
float *salaire;
salaire = NULL;
scanf("%f", salaire);
printf("\nLe salaire : %f", *salaire);
```

Comment: @Cody-Code It has undefined behavior because there is used a null-pointer to write to memory.

Comment: You are trying to read a value into the memory address that `salaire` points to; but that point to nothing (NULL) so the read causes undefined behaviour - and crashes.

Answer (score -1):

You need to identify the place where you can store this float value and null means no space exist so you should allocate space for it. I recommend replace second line by :

```
salaire=malloc(sizeof(float));
```

Comment: A better option would just be to use a local temporary and pass the address of it. That way, you avoid pointless dynamic memory allocation.

Comment: "null means no space exist" is inaccurate. NULL assigned to a pointer just means the pointer isn't pointing to a valid memory location. If I performed the above malloc operation and then assigned the pointer to NULL then the memory allocated by malloc would still exist. It just wouldn't be accessible by the pointer.

Comment: Also I suggest adding the note to perform the free() operation to deallocate the memory when the program is done with using the memory pointed to by salaire since memory management is on the programmer.